# Segmentation fault when inserting into the stringstream

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stringstream

I get a segmentation fault, but I don't use any pointers. It's being happened when I insert into the stringstream.

```
std::string Relations::toString()
{
    std::stringstream restring;
    restring << ID << "(";

    restring << reList[0]; // segmentation fault

    for (int c = 1; c < reList.size(); c++)
    {
        restring << "," << reList[c];
    }

    restring << ")";
    return restring.str();
}
```

Comment: Well, to start with, there's going to be an obvious crash if the vector is empty, or has only one element.

Comment: You don't seem to check whether `reList` has sufficient size before accessing second item at `reList[1];`. Also item indexes in C/C++ typically start from 0.

Comment: Please show the calls leading to the segfault.

Comment: Could also be a bad `this` pointer. Lot of possibilities. [mcve] please.

Comment: are you sure you mean [1] and not [0]? Does the list have any entries in it. use reList.at(x) instead of [x]. you will get better diagnostic

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the `reList[0]` you have to check it exists.

```
std::string Relations::toString()
{
    std::stringstream restring;
    restring << ID << "(";

    if (reList.size() > 0)
    {
        restring << reList[0];
        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < reList.size(); ++i)
        {
            restring << "," << reList[i];
        }
    }

    restring << ")";
    return restring.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, making me realize that this was a dumb question. I was using this class wrong in another class and there was nothing going into my vector. Therefore, I was trying to access the empty vector.